# A regex to satisfy the grammar police (there vs. their vs they're)

Tags: code-golf, regular-expression

We've all been burned by the grammar police on the internet. What we need is a regex that can be used in place of "there", "their", and "they're". This would shift burden of grammar parsing from the writer to the reader (a sort of "client-side" grammar, if we you will). So, here's what I have to start with:

`the([re]|[ir]|[y're]).`

...but I'm positive there's room for optimization.

What's the shortest regex that could be used in place of any variation or the aforementioned homohpones?

Comment: Your regex isn't correct. It matches `ther`, `thee`, `thei`, `they` and `the'`. Can't dig up a link right now, but look up "character classes". (Followed by any character if the `.` is supposed to be part of the regex, but that seems like a formatting mistake.)

Comment: Bit off-topic with no objective winning criterion, but could actually be a cool challenge.

Comment: @carusocomputing I believe it's a [golfing tips question](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/1723/lets-decide-what-kind-of-non-challenge-questions-we-want-once-and-for-all) which is definitely on topic.

Comment: Knot ay gud eye deal too mi. Gust rite it rite.

Comment: As worded the correct answer to the question is `.*`, but I'm sure that's not what you intended to ask. Also, spelling is not grammar. You should be complaining about the orthography police, not the grammar police.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

There isn't a lot of room for optimisation here. This seems to be optimal:

```
the(y're|re|ir)
```

The only alternative I can think of avoids the duplication of `re` but ends up at the same byte count (and it's potentially worse in flavours where meta characters need to be escaped to work):

```
the((y')?re|ir)
```